# android shortcut key to open the application

Tags: android, key, shortcut

I want my application to get opened when user presses some shortcut key. Say long hold of 9 button on the key pad(the key pad here i specified is soft key pad which opens when user clicks on phone icon). can i able to capture that event? is there any broadcast receivers are there or please specify any Technic.

Comment: Why not create a widget for your application and ask the user to place it on his home screen ?

Answer (score 0):

You can see  [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

Key events are generally accompanied by a key code (getKeyCode()), scan code (getScanCode())
Key code constants are defined in this class. Scan code constants are raw device-specific codes obtained from the OS and so are not generally meaningful to applications unless interpreted using the KeyCharacterMap.